In PGFPLOTS, x-tick value being "rounded" from 1024 to 1020 in log-log plot with "log ticks with fixed point"
In the following example, I'm not sure why the last x-tick is showing as 1020 rather than 1024. I assume it's a number formatting issue. Any advice is very much appreciated! I include a MWE and example output below.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    ticks=major,
    scale only axis,
    width=4in, height=2in,
    ytick distance=10,
    xtick={16,32,64,128,256,512,1024},
    log ticks with fixed point,
    every axis plot/.append style={
      samples at={16,32,64,128,256,512,1024}},
    ]
    \addplot[blue,dashed,mark=*]{8*x^4/1e6};
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}



The fix is given here, add
xticklabel={
  \pgfmathparse{int(2^\tick)}
  \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}
},

(I think that \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true} is now useless).
Example (I added log basis x=2, which is more appropriate; so you don't have to specify explicitly xticks).
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    ticks=major,  
    scale only axis,
    width=4in, height=2in,
    ytick distance=10,
    log basis x=2,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xticklabel={
      \pgfmathparse{int(2^\tick)}
      \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}
    },
    samples at={16,32,64,128,256,512,1024},
    ]
    \addplot[blue,dashed,mark=*]{8*x^4/1e6};
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Excellent. Thanks for your help!
